# Tab Bar Controller--> Table View Controller Not Updating On Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a tab bar controller linking to a table view controller,
It all seems fine except in my static table view controller the titles I write and the symbols I selected are not shown on the simulator.

What is the problem?
Should I add a navigation controller write before the table view controller?

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance overriding the data source methods in your tableViewController? (e.g., numberOfSectionsInTableView:)

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}
This code is there by standard and I didn't touch it in anyway. I was hoping to only use storyboards for this task. Do I need to do some coding also?

Comment: Remove/comment out that code along with other methods related to the tableView data source.

Comment: yep that did it, write an official answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments in the question, removing/commenting out all tableView data source methods fixed the issue of the static tableView not displaying the static cells. I am glad that helped.